# 'Camunda > Admin > Authorization' changes requires restart to take effect

Tags: bpmn, camunda

I have created a spring-starter project with camunda 7.15.0. In addition for demo purposes, I configured and integrated Apache DS for users and groups. I am able to get users and groups.

[image: Camunda Groups fetched from ApacheDS]

Further, I removed the default group camunda-all and used AD groups from the screenshot. So,

- *HMS Victory* was able to access only Cockpit
- *HMS Bounty* was able to access only 'Tasklist'
- *HMS Lydia* had no access to the system

> This works too and gives expected result.

**However, any change to 'Camunda > Admin > Authorization' requires restart to take effect.** Otherwise the changes do not take effect. Any change required to make AD Group changes take effect at run time ? Below is my Groups configuration.

[image: Camunda Application Authorizations]

Comment: Please describe how you have integrated, what configurations you have set, and how you are testing if changes have been picked up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be application behavior. When you logout from Camunda Webapp, the URL does not go back to Welcome page. When I closed the browser tab, or used the default url `http://localhost:8080` then it worked. For more details, [use default url to login to Camunda](https://forum.camunda.org/t/camunda-admin-authorization-changes-requires-restart-to-take-effect/29476/2?u=sourabh_parsekar)